# Setting actor size according to screen size in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a simple game using libgdx in android. I created an actor. I want to resize the actor according to the screen size. Can anyone please suggest me a simple tutorial to do the same

Answer (score 3):

well it depends on how you set the viewport of your Stage.

lets say your stage viewport is set to `stage.setViewport(16,10,false)` within your resize()-method.
This way, your screen will always show the region from (0,0) in the bottom left to (16,10) in the top-right corner...

If you create an Actor with width=8 and height=5, it will always be half of the screen width and half of the screen height big.

Of course, the example above will usually distort your screen when it resizes... So you could use the `setViewport(16,10,true);` This way, you will keep the aspect ratio, but might need to  resize or reposition some actors within the resize() method, e.g. when they are to be shown on the right edge of the screen.

The other way is by setting the viewport to the same coordinate systems as the pixels on the screen: `stage.setViewport(width,height,false);` (within the resize(...)-method). This way, one unit in the stage coordinate system equals one pixel on the screen.

When doing so, you will have to resize the actors in the resize() method after setting the viewport:

```
actor.setSize(0.2f*stage.getWidth(), 0.2f*stage.getWidth() * actor.getHeight()/actor.getWidth()):
```

Doing so will always make the actor be exactly one fifth of the screen width and have its height matched so it doesn't get distorted.

Hope this helps a bit...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version (nightlies) you may have seen the [`Viewport`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) class.
This class is what you are looking for. Lets say you have a 1600 * 900px monitor and you set your `Viewport to 16 * 9`, every unit in your `Viewport` will be 100px on your `Screen`.
This means, if you set your `Stage`s `Viewport` to 16 * 9 an `Actor` with the size of 1 will be 100*100px big. If you are using a 800*450px monitor it will be 50*50px big.
There are also different `Viewport` types:

- `StretchViewport`: Your `Virtual Viewport` gets stretched to fill the whole `Screen`. So if you have a 1600 * 900 monitor and a `Virtual Viewport` of 16/10, a 1x1 `Actor` will be 100px wide, but only 90px heigh. So the aspect ratio is not the same anymore.
- `FitViewport`: If your `Virtual Viewport` has a different aspect ratio the `Screen` will be filled with black bars. So on a 1600*900 `Screen` with 16/10 virtual Viewport a collumn of 80px width on both sides of the Screen will be black (`(virtualWidth / wirtualHeight) * realHeight = realWidth`, `physicalWidth - realWidth = blackWidth`, to have the game in center `blackWidth/2` on both sides), to keep aspect ratio.

There are also others, but those are the most important 2 imho. You can read more on the [article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) i linked.
If you are not using the latest nightlies, you need to use camera. The constructor of the `OrthographicCamera` takes the viewport width and height. Those are the same as for the viewport. The difference is, that it is a "StretchViewport" automatically, so you have to manually set the glViewport like in [this tutorial](http://www.acamara.es/blog/2012/02/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/).

I hope i could help.